# Castle - Property injection does not resolve dependency when injecting component with constructor injected typed factory

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

A depended property does not get resolved when it uses a constructor injected factory method. However if the factory method is resolved before resolving the depended component everything is working as expected. Also when using exclusively property injection or constructor injection everything is working.  See the code below showing working and not working scenarios (it uses Microsoft unit test framework).

Is it a not supported scenario (and is there a reason for that) or is it a bug?

```
using System;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace CastleTest
{
    public interface IFuncDep
    {}

    internal class FuncDep : IFuncDep
    {}

    internal class UsingFuncDepPropInjected
    {
        public Func<IFuncDep> FuncDepProp { get; set; }
    }

    internal class UsingFuncDepConsInjected
    {
        public Func<IFuncDep> FuncDepProp { get; private set; }

        public UsingFuncDepConsInjected(Func<IFuncDep> funcDepProp)
        {
            FuncDepProp = funcDepProp;
        }
    }

    internal class PropInjectedUsingConsInjected
    {
        public UsingFuncDepConsInjected FuncDep { get; set; }
    }

    internal class PropInjectedUsingPropInjected
    {
        public UsingFuncDepPropInjected FuncDep { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ConsInjectedUsingPropInjected
    {
        public UsingFuncDepPropInjected FuncDep { get; private set; }

        public ConsInjectedUsingPropInjected(UsingFuncDepPropInjected funcDep)
        {
            FuncDep = funcDep;
        }
    }

    internal class ConsInjectedUsingConsInjected
    {
        public UsingFuncDepConsInjected FuncDep { get; private set; }

        public ConsInjectedUsingConsInjected(UsingFuncDepConsInjected funcDep)
        {
            FuncDep = funcDep;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class CastleTest
    {
        private WindsorContainer _container;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitContainer()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();

            _container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

            _container.Register(
                Component.For<IFuncDep>().UsingFactoryMethod((k, c) => new FuncDep()).LifeStyle.Transient);
            //_container.Register(Component.For<IFuncDep>().ImplementedBy<FuncDep>().LifeStyle.Transient);

            _container.Register(Component.For<UsingFuncDepPropInjected>());
            _container.Register(Component.For<UsingFuncDepConsInjected>());
            _container.Register(Component.For<PropInjectedUsingConsInjected>());
            _container.Register(Component.For<PropInjectedUsingPropInjected>());
            _container.Register(Component.For<ConsInjectedUsingPropInjected>());
            _container.Register(Component.For<ConsInjectedUsingConsInjected>());

            var handlers = _container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object));
            foreach (var handler in handlers)
            {
                foreach (var serviceType in handler.ComponentModel.Services)
                {
                    Console.Write(serviceType.Name);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(": {0}", handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ConstructorInjectionWithinPropertyInjection_Failing()
        {
            //var func = container.Resolve<Func<IFuncDep>>();
            //Assert.IsNotNull(func);
            //IFuncDep value = func();
            //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(value, typeof(FuncDep));
            //when the block above is uncommented, everything gets working (see ConstructorInjectionWithinPropertyInjection_ManualFuncResolveBeforePropResolve_Ok)

            var o = _container.Resolve<PropInjectedUsingConsInjected>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(o);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep.FuncDepProp);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void PropertyInjectionWithinPropertyInjection_Ok()
        {
            var o = _container.Resolve<PropInjectedUsingPropInjected>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(o);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep.FuncDepProp);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ConstructorInjectionWithinPropertyInjection_ManualFuncResolveBeforePropResolve_Ok()
        {
            var func = _container.Resolve<Func<IFuncDep>>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(func);
            IFuncDep value = func();
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(value, typeof(FuncDep));

            var o = _container.Resolve<PropInjectedUsingConsInjected>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(o);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep.FuncDepProp);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void PropertyInjectionWithinConstructorInjection_Ok()
        {
            var o = _container.Resolve<ConsInjectedUsingPropInjected>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(o);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep.FuncDepProp);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ConstructorInjectionWithinConstructorInjection_Ok()
        {
            var o = _container.Resolve<ConsInjectedUsingConsInjected>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(o);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep);
            Assert.IsNotNull(o.FuncDep.FuncDepProp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not registering `Func<IFuncDep>` in your configuration. The code below should work:

```
_container.Register(Component.For<IFuncDep>().ImplementedBy<FuncDep>().LifeStyle.Transient);
_container.Register(Component.For<Func<IFuncDep>>().AsFactory().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The proposed solution works.

However I would like to understand why the other cases are working fine even without explicit registration of the `Func<IFuncDep>` as factory. The factory should be automatically resolved due to  `_container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();` (and it really IS resolved in all cases marked as _Ok).